# Text animation using jQuery or possibly a plugin

Tags: text, animated

I tried creating a flash effect like [this header](http://www.abbingtonpartners.com/) using jQuery so it would work on mobile devices. The more I searched and added different things, the more complicated I made it. Here's the [code in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BEZuGfs2). I cannot get this to work the way that matches the website header I referenced. Is there any easier way or a Wordpress plugin that would do something like this on the homepage header?

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://lukeas14.github.com/animateText.js/ plugin, the site is well documented, hope it helps